# How to grep twice?

Tags: grep

```
[user@notebook ~]$ printf 'adgaa alpha lajsd assa ><>4 saf\n63SXYZae fkrk safXYZek\nsaf betf!%saa sDGFXYZFalf\n'
adgaa alpha lajsd assa ><>4 saf
63SXYZae fkrk safXYZek
saf betf!aa sDGFXYZFalf
[user@notebook ~]$ 
[user@notebook ~]$ printf 'adgaa alpha lajsd assa ><>4 saf\n63SXYZae fkrk safXYZek\nsaf betf!%saa sDGFXYZFalf\n' | grep SOMEMAGIC
63SXYZae fkrk safXYZek
[user@notebook ~]$
```

**Question:** how can I grep for only those lines that has a given string twice? In this example the string was "XYZ". Between the two strings, there could be anything.

Comment: Clarify please?

Comment: How to know which string you are looking for that occurs twice?

Comment: What's wrong with `grep 'PATTERN.*PATTERN'` or, if the PATTERN is complex, `P='PATTERN' grep "$P.*$P"` ?

Comment: @AdamKatz - the problem - as i see it - is that a PATTERN is not a match - the PATTERN might match any of several strings in several contexts

Answer (score 2):

Grepping twice wouldn't bring you any benefit. I'd go for using egrep in combination with a regex that matches you need.

```
ps ax | egrep '(a.*){2}'
```

That would give you all processes, that have the 'a' twice. You can of course use that on any kind of input egrep can read.

Comment: Your pattern is wrong; it doesn't match all names with duplicates. To me `(a.*){2}` looks more reliable as a general ERE pattern to check a duplicate.

Comment: You're correct. The result of my RegEx just looked right at first sight to me, but your's is actually working as requested. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: This sort of regex is expensive, approaching a [ReDoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReDoS "Regular Expression Denial of Service") because there are so many possibilities to match given a string with lots of the letter `a` in it.

Comment: @Janis - your pattern is wrong. You don't match a string followed by itself - you match two successive strings which match the same pattern.

Comment: @mikeserv, I don't think so. The pattern in the example contains the sample strings "a", followed by an arbitrary string, and again by the same, thus you match the constant string pattern twice. That was exactly the requirement of the question; "a **given** string twice".

Comment: @Janis - In this example the string is XYZ - and anyway, you don't match the string twice, you match the pattern twice. It will work - for a lot strings - but it will not for pattern characters, for example, because then you have to escape them with other pattern characters, and that differentiates it from the string. And last, your comment calls it a *general ERE pattern to check a duplicate* which is what I disputed.

Comment: @mikeserv, I see where you're comming from, but please be fair and interpret my response in the context of the question, even if you think my wording was not perfect. (You initially said, my pattern was wrong, but it wasn't. The ERE pattern I gave solves the question to match a **given** string that appears twice on a line.)

Comment: For the other reader here an explanation of mikeserv's comment. To solve the question of repetitions of **arbitrary** (unknown in advance) patterns you'd need some method that goes beyond regular expressions; some libraries support it using so called back-references which require (non-regular) backtracking algorithms. For a repetition of **given** (known in advance) strings, which was the question here, you can use an ERE pattern like the one that I posted, where the sample character `a` should of course be replaced by the actual string to look for (the OP used `XYZ`; it's also only a sample).

Answer (score 0):

With regular expressions you can either *back-reference* a `(`grouped pattern`)`or you can specify that a match must `{`repeat`}` it. The difference between one and the other is significant. For a simple example consider the string:

```
baa
```

... when matched against the following two patterns:

```
\([ba]\)\{2\}
\([ba]\)\1
```

For the first of these the grouping is actually irrelevant because the pattern searches for a single character - when specifying repetitions the the grouping is only important in that it can contain a whole subexpression to which the repetition can refer. And so, for this simple example case...

```
 [ba]\{2\}
```

... and ...

```
\([ba]\)\{2\}
```

...are synonymous and can be taken to mean that the match engine should look for the leftmost and longest string in input that is composed of two characters - either of *b* or *a*. The repetition applies to the *pattern* which makes the *match* and *not* to the contents of the match. So it literally means:

```
[ba][ba]
```

....in the same way...

```
\(a.*\)\{2\}
```

...means...

```
a.*a.*
```

...which would work ok for the single character *a* but which is not a good example of how to match a matched string a second time.

For our input sample this gets...

```
ba
```

But the back-reference is very different - it is a reference to the *content of the match*. The simple example case gets...

```
aa
```

...because that is the leftmost and longest string in input that is comprised of a character that matches the subexpression's `[ba]` pattern and which is immediately followed by *itself* - not the pattern which matched the character.

So you want:

```
\(pattern\).*\1
```

Because a regular expression *pattern* and the string which it matches are not the same - else we wouldn't have much call to use regular expressions in the first place. To demonstrate the difference with a slightly more complicated input example consider the following:

```
printf %s\\n 123ABC321 123ABC123 321ABC321 |
grep '\([123]\{3\}.*\)\{2\}'
```

The `grep` above will print:

```
123ABC321
123ABC123
321ABC321
```

...because in every case the *pattern* is successfully matched twice. But if the `grep` line were replaced with:

```
grep '\([123]\{3\}\).*\1'
```

... it would only print ...

```
123ABC123
321ABC321
```

Comment: With `[]` you're using character classes. I might be wrong, but I was under the impression, that you can't do `[test]` (notice the double t) with character classes. Hence, you can't search for an exact string that way.

Comment: @Daniel - No - a character class matches a character as a part of a pattern - you're right that you cannot match a fixed string within a character class except that the string is a single char and the class is comprised only of it. What you can do is match a pattern, group it, and back-reference the match - and so match the match a second time rather than the pattern - that's the point of this answer. It allows you to more freely compose your search pattern as you are not limited to fixed strings in your pattern and can yet rely on the identical first/second matches. Use `grep -F` for fixed.